# parent kendo panelbar item is triggered when clicking on the sub kendo panelbar item

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

I have a kendo angular ui panelbar used in the sidepanel as a treemenu with submenu's in it. The panelbar is actually linked to the angular router routes array (and as such each item has a path which is set using routerLink).

The problem is that when I open up the submenu *the path of the **parent** menuitem is followed when the childitem is 'active'*. (active === selected) *The path of the **child** menuitem is effectively followed when the childitem is not yet 'active'..*

In other words, it looks as if **the parent menuitem '*hijacks*' the menu when the child item is 'active'/selected**... Is this normal behavior ? Anyone experience with this and knows a way to avoid this ?

To give an idea how we use it, this is how our template looks like (although a bit simplified, we set more params) :

```
<kendo-panelbar (stateChange)="onPanelChange($event)">
    <kendo-panelbar-item *ngFor="let item of items"
                         [title]=""(item?.content) | async""
                         [routerLink]="item?.routerLink"
                         [routerLinkActive]="'k-state-selected'"
                         [expanded]="(isExpanded() && (isRouterLinkActive(item?.routerLink) || isChildRouterLinkActive(item)))"
                         (click)="onPanelClick(item)">
                        <kendo-panelbar-item *ngFor="let child of item.children"
                                             [title]="(child?.content) | async"
                                             [routerLink]="child?.routerLink"
                                             [routerLinkActive]="'k-state-selected'">
                        </kendo-panelbar-item>
    </kendo-panelbar-item>
</kendo-panelbar>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not the best solution, but I fixed this by stepping away from the routerLink and do the router navigation myself *and* detecting if we are still on the same route or not

As stated [**here** in the kendo documentation](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/layout/panelbar/routing/) the navigation approaches that the PanelBar supports are either using the RouterLink directive or using the stateChange event.

So :

> 1. I now do the navigation in the stateChange event (removed routerLink from the template)
> 2. I keep the routerlink url in the ID (using router.createUrlTree and urlSerializer.serialize to compose the url) so it gets passed to the stateChange event
> 3. I check in the stateChange event if the current route equals the selected items routerlink url (from the ID) and only navigate if it's
>      different

This is now the stateChange event :

```
public onPanelChange(event: any) {
    if ((event != null) && (event instanceof Array)) {
        let filteredItem = event.find(x => x.selected == true);
        if (typeof filteredItem != 'undefined') {
            if (this.router.url != filteredItem.id.toString())
                this.router.navigate([filteredItem.id.toString()]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the template :

```
<kendo-panelbar (stateChange)="onPanelChange($event)">
    <kendo-panelbar-item *ngFor="let item of items"
                         [title]=""(item?.content) | async""
                         [id]="urlSerialised(item?.routerLink)"
                         [routerLinkActive]="'k-state-selected'" >
                        <kendo-panelbar-item *ngFor="let child of item.children"
                                             [title]="(child?.content) | async"
                                             [id]="urlSerialised(child?.routerLink)"
                                             [routerLinkActive]="'k-state-selected'">
                        </kendo-panelbar-item>
    </kendo-panelbar-item>
</kendo-panelbar>
```

This is how I compose the url :

```
 public urlSerialised(commands: string[]) {
        try {
            let urlTree: UrlTree = this.router.createUrlTree(commands);
            return this.urlSerializer.serialize(urlTree)
        }
        catch (e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```